# Swift - Custom object found nil even though objectId is accurate

Tags: swift, parse-platform

```
        let parent = path[row-1]
        let child = path[row]

        let indexOfChild = matrix[parent.objectId!]!.index(of: child)

        print("indexOfChild = \(indexOfChild)")
        print("keyValuePair = \(matrix[parent.objectId!]!)")
        print("child = \(child)")

        let indexAfter =  matrix[parent.objectId!]!.index(after: indexOfChild!)
```

As a result i'm getting this information printed in console.

As you can see "child" (which is the argument object with argumentText: "example") exists in the keyValuePair (they have the same objectId). Yet, it's index in keyValuePair appears nil in console. Apparently, the mere difference is: "child" has **"0x608000333f60"** next to it whereas the second argument object in keyValuePair has **"0x600000321a40"**.

**I don't know the purpose of these and how they get calculated but it seems to me index is found nil because these codes are different from each other**

I have been trying to fix it for too long now. Could someone please help me through it?

---

```html
indexOfChild = nil
keyValuePair = [<Argument: 0x608000334e60, objectId: IG9ekqMRw9, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x60800042f200>";
    argumentText = "the only thing is I can't get over how I feel when it ";
    creatorId = hWRXoRvnYd;
    level = 4;
    parentId = j7GkpwUKsm;
    reach = 0;
    threadId = Dtq632QYJ2;
}, <Argument: 0x600000321a40, objectId: 56AsB1juNP, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x600000235440>";
    argumentText = "example ";
    creatorId = hWRXoRvnYd;
    level = 4;
    parentId = j7GkpwUKsm;
    reach = 0;
    threadId = Dtq632QYJ2;
}]
child = <Argument: 0x608000333f60, objectId: 56AsB1juNP, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x608000235540>";
    argumentText = "example ";
    creatorId = hWRXoRvnYd;
    level = 4;
    parentId = j7GkpwUKsm;
    reach = 0;
    threadId = Dtq632QYJ2;
}
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **0x608000333f60** and **0x600000321a40** values are memory address locations for the relevant variables. Since the address locations are different, I believe the two child instances are treated as two separate values and probably will not match. And that might be the issue you are running into.

It might be better to check the parent for the child instance by a unique ID value so that you can match the child instance in the parent array correctly. Does that make sense?

You can find the index for the child this way:

```
var index = -1
var found = false
for chld in matrix[parent.objectId!]! {
    index = index + 1
    if chld.objectId == child.objectId {
        found = true
        break
    }
}
if found {
    // The index value at this point is the index for the child
}
```

You could also simply filter the child array to find the child in the parent array which has the same objectId as your `child` variable and then find the index from the child array, something like this:

```
let chld = matrix[parent.objectId!]!.filter{ $0.objectId == child.objectId }.first
let indexOfChild = matrix[parent.objectId!]!.index(of: chld)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but i didn't quite get what you meant by unique ID.. I am thinking objectIds (which are given automatically every time I create a new instance) must fulfil the need for identifying the rest of the instance. Am I wrong? Isn't there a way for me to simply filter out  memory address locations when I query objects from backend?

Comment: Yes, you can use the objectId as the unique ID. You can do something like the code segment I'll add to my answer above to find the child with the matching objectID.

Comment: Thank you very much mate! I have spent all day figured this out and finally got it thanks to you:)

Comment: Happy to help :) Could you please mark the answer as "correct" if it helped?